# converting JSON object ot array of JSON objects on basis of key - Code in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have an array of JSON object. The sample array is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "evt.category": "file",
    "evt.cpu": 0,
    "evt.num": 10078507,
    "evt.res": "SUCCESS",
    "evt.time": 1532841047277584400,
    "evt.type": "read",
    "fd.filename": "libnss_files.so.2",
    "fd.name": "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2",
    "fd.num": 13,
    "fd.type": "file",
    "fd.uid": "1996913",
    "proc.loginshellid": 19968,
    "proc.name": "last",
    "proc.pid": 19969,
    "thread.ismain": true,
    "thread.tid": 19969
  },
  {
    "evt.buffer": "1000",
    "evt.category": "file",
    "evt.cpu": 0,
    "evt.num": 10078564,
    "evt.res": "SUCCESS",
    "evt.time": 1532841047277731300,
    "evt.type": "read",
    "fd.filename": "loginuid",
    "fd.name": "/proc/16009/loginuid",
    "fd.num": 13,
    "fd.type": "file",
    "fd.uid": "1996913",
    "proc.loginshellid": 19968,
    "proc.name": "last",
    "proc.pid": 19969,
    "thread.ismain": true,
    "thread.tid": 19969
  },
  {
    "evt.buffer": "",
    "evt.category": "file",
    "evt.cpu": 0,
    "evt.num": 10078566,
    "evt.res": "SUCCESS",
    "evt.time": 1532841047277733400,
    "evt.type": "read",
    "fd.filename": "loginuid",
    "fd.name": "/proc/16009/loginuid",
    "fd.num": 13,
    "fd.type": "file",
    "fd.uid": "1996913",
    "proc.loginshellid": 19968,
    "proc.name": "last",
    "proc.pid": 19969,
    "thread.ismain": true,
    "thread.tid": 19969
  }
]
```

I want to re-structure this array such that each object is converted into another array and each array should contain JSON objects on the basis of these keys like a JSON object of `evt` , `proc` `thread` etc.

I tried some online websites to do that but none of it work.

Please Help.

**EDIT:**
My desired output is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "evt": {
      "category": "file",
      "cpu": 0,
      "num": 10078507,
      "res": "SUCCESS",
      "time": 1532841047277584400,
      "type": "read"
    },
    "fd": {
      "filename": "libnss_files.so.2",
      "name": "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2",
      "num": 13,
      "type": "file",
      "uid": "1996913"
    },
    "proc": {
      "loginshellid": 19968,
      "name": "last",
      "pid": 19969
    },
    "thread": {
      "ismain": true,
      "tid": 19969
    }
  },
  {
    "evt": {
      "buffer": "1000",
    "category": "file",
    "cpu": 0,
    "num": 10078564,
    "res": "SUCCESS",
    "time": 1532841047277731300,
    "type": "read"
    },
    "fd": {
    "filename": "loginuid",
    "name": "/proc/16009/loginuid",
    "num": 13,
    "type": "file",
    "uid": "1996913"
    },
    "proc": {
      "loginshellid": 19968,
    "name": "last",
    "pid": 19969
    },
    "thread" : {
    "ismain": true,
    "tid": 19969
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Could you please add example for your desire output?

Comment: @DavidWinder I have added it in the question now. Hope now my question is more clear. Thanks.

Comment: @cstayyab, which programming language would you like to do this conversion?

Comment: @BráulioFigueiredo , I didn't mention specific programming language because in my view there may be a generic way to do it ( e.g. loops). But to be specific, it's better to be in **python 3**

Comment: @cstayyab Unfortunatly I don't know python, but I solve your probem in Javascript. Check my answer if it helps

Comment: In every programming language, the approach is to load the JSON, modify the data in memory and to write the changed representation again. Start with either subtask and ask here if you have specific problems. Don't treat SO as a coding service though, even if two users here already jumped on in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json

list_of_objects = json.loads(json_string)

new_list = []
for complex_object in list_of_objects:
    new_object = {}
    for composite_key, value in complex_object.items():
        key, subkey = composite_key.split(".")
        if key not in new_object:
            new_object[key] = {}
        new_object[key][subkey] = value
    new_list.append(new_object)

json_string = json.dumps(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about python but this is how you can do it with JS

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "evt.category": "file",
    "evt.cpu": 0,
    "evt.num": 10078507,
    "evt.res": "SUCCESS",
    "evt.time": 1532841047277584400,
    "evt.type": "read",
    "fd.filename": "libnss_files.so.2",
    "fd.name": "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2",
    "fd.num": 13,
    "fd.type": "file",
    "fd.uid": "1996913",
    "proc.loginshellid": 19968,
    "proc.name": "last",
    "proc.pid": 19969,
    "thread.ismain": true,
    "thread.tid": 19969
  },
  {
    "evt.buffer": "1000",
    "evt.category": "file",
    "evt.cpu": 0,
    "evt.num": 10078564,
    "evt.res": "SUCCESS",
    "evt.time": 1532841047277731300,
    "evt.type": "read",
    "fd.filename": "loginuid",
    "fd.name": "/proc/16009/loginuid",
    "fd.num": 13,
    "fd.type": "file",
    "fd.uid": "1996913",
    "proc.loginshellid": 19968,
    "proc.name": "last",
    "proc.pid": 19969,
    "thread.ismain": true,
    "thread.tid": 19969
  },
  {
    "evt.buffer": "",
    "evt.category": "file",
    "evt.cpu": 0,
    "evt.num": 10078566,
    "evt.res": "SUCCESS",
    "evt.time": 1532841047277733400,
    "evt.type": "read",
    "fd.filename": "loginuid",
    "fd.name": "/proc/16009/loginuid",
    "fd.num": 13,
    "fd.type": "file",
    "fd.uid": "1996913",
    "proc.loginshellid": 19968,
    "proc.name": "last",
    "proc.pid": 19969,
    "thread.ismain": true,
    "thread.tid": 19969
  }
]


const newArr = arr.map(obj =>{
  
    const newObj = {};

    for(let key in obj){
      const [mainKey,subKey] =  key.split('.')
      if(newObj[mainKey] === undefined){
        newObj[mainKey] = {}
      } 
       newObj[mainKey][subKey] = obj[key];
    }
    
    return newObj
    
    
})

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: I like the way you did the thing but I am passing an output of program (Sysdig) to my program and sadly, sysdig cannot call a JS file. Besides I also have to do more things after conversion which I cannot do in JS.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj = [{
        "evt.category": "file",
        "evt.cpu": 0,
        "evt.num": 10078507,
        "evt.res": "SUCCESS",
        "evt.time": 1532841047277584400,
        "evt.type": "read",
        "fd.filename": "libnss_files.so.2",
        "fd.name": "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2",
        "fd.num": 13,
        "fd.type": "file",
        "fd.uid": "1996913",
        "proc.loginshellid": 19968,
        "proc.name": "last",
        "proc.pid": 19969,
        "thread.ismain": true,
        "thread.tid": 19969
    },
    {
        "evt.buffer": "1000",
        "evt.category": "file",
        "evt.cpu": 0,
        "evt.num": 10078564,
        "evt.res": "SUCCESS",
        "evt.time": 1532841047277731300,
        "evt.type": "read",
        "fd.filename": "loginuid",
        "fd.name": "/proc/16009/loginuid",
        "fd.num": 13,
        "fd.type": "file",
        "fd.uid": "1996913",
        "proc.loginshellid": 19968,
        "proc.name": "last",
        "proc.pid": 19969,
        "thread.ismain": true,
        "thread.tid": 19969
    },
    {
        "evt.buffer": "",
        "evt.category": "file",
        "evt.cpu": 0,
        "evt.num": 10078566,
        "evt.res": "SUCCESS",
        "evt.time": 1532841047277733400,
        "evt.type": "read",
        "fd.filename": "loginuid",
        "fd.name": "/proc/16009/loginuid",
        "fd.num": 13,
        "fd.type": "file",
        "fd.uid": "1996913",
        "proc.loginshellid": 19968,
        "proc.name": "last",
        "proc.pid": 19969,
        "thread.ismain": true,
        "thread.tid": 19969
    }
];

function convertObj(obj) {
    var resultArray = [];
    obj.forEach(item => {
        var resultObj = {};
        for (var property in item) {
            var array = property.split('.');
            var reference = resultObj;
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
                if (!reference[array[i]]){
                    reference[array[i]] = {};
                }
                reference = reference[array[i]];
            }
            reference[array[array.length-1]] = item[property];
        }
        resultArray.push(resultObj);
    });
    return resultArray;
}

console.log(convertObj(obj));
```

Comment: It is not giving required output. It's showing only first sub key value in each object.

Comment: Is true... fixed  :)

Answer (score 1):

The task can be accomplished easily enough using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), e.g. using the jq executable, the python jq module, or the python pyjq module.

Whichever mode you choose, a suitable filter would be:

```
def restructure:
  def splitup: index(".") as $ix | [ .[0:$ix], .[1+$ix:] ];
  to_entries
  | map( (.key|splitup) + [.value] )
  | reduce .[] as $x ({}; .[$x[0]][$x[1]] = $x[2]) ;

map(restructure)
```

### Example (using the jq executable)

With the sample input, the invocation:

```
jq -f program.jq input.jq
```

yields:

```
[
  {
    "evt": {
      "category": "file",
      "cpu": 0,
      "num": 10078507,
      "res": "SUCCESS",
      "time": 1532841047277584400,
      "type": "read"
    },
    "fd": {
      "num": 13,
      "name": "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2",
      "filename": "libnss_files.so.2",
      "type": "file",
      "uid": "1996913"
    },
    "proc": {
      "loginshellid": 19968,
      "name": "last",
      "pid": 19969
    },
    "thread": {
      "ismain": true,
      "tid": 19969
    }
  },
  {
    "evt": {
      "buffer": "1000",
      "category": "file",
      "cpu": 0,
      "num": 10078564,
      "res": "SUCCESS",
      "time": 1532841047277731300,
      "type": "read"
    },
    "fd": {
      "name": "/proc/16009/loginuid",
      "filename": "loginuid",
      "num": 13,
      "type": "file",
      "uid": "1996913"
    },
    "proc": {
      "loginshellid": 19968,
      "name": "last",
      "pid": 19969
    },
    "thread": {
      "ismain": true,
      "tid": 19969
    }
  },
  {
    "evt": {
      "buffer": "",
      "category": "file",
      "cpu": 0,
      "num": 10078566,
      "res": "SUCCESS",
      "time": 1532841047277733400,
      "type": "read"
    },
    "fd": {
      "name": "/proc/16009/loginuid",
      "filename": "loginuid",
      "num": 13,
      "type": "file",
      "uid": "1996913"
    },
    "proc": {
      "loginshellid": 19968,
      "name": "last",
      "pid": 19969
    },
    "thread": {
      "ismain": true,
      "tid": 19969
    }
  }
]
```

### Robustification

The above assumes all the key names have at least one ".".  If that cannot be assumed, then the following variant of `restructure` could be used:

```
def restructure:
  def splitup: index(".") as $ix
    | if $ix then [ .[0:$ix], .[1+$ix:] ]
      else [ ., null] 
      end;
  to_entries
  | map( (.key|splitup) + [.value] )
  | reduce .[] as $x ({};
      if $x[1] == null then .[$x[0]] = $x[2]
      else .[$x[0]][$x[1]] = $x[2]
      end ) ;
```